# How to show label component when AjaxLink is clicked

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

When Ajaxlink is clicked, I need to display data from the JSON file. I have implemented the following code which is not working. Please correct my code if I did any mistake. (is it possible to add a label inside AjaxLink)

Thanks in advance.

```
AjaxLink<Void> jsonData = new AjaxLink<Void>("jsonData") {

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                File jsonFile;
                try {
                    jsonFile = new File(fileLocation);

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, JsonNode.class);
                Label jsonLabel = new Label("jsonLabel",
                            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode));
                jsonLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                jsonLabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
                target.add(jsonLabel);
                addOrReplace(jsonLabel);
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        add(jsonData);
```

Html:

```
               <div>
                    <a wicket:id="jsonData" class="text-white">View Template</a>
                    <pre wicket:id="jsonLabel" class="text-white bg-dark"> </pre>
                </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are not adding your newly created `Label jsonLabel` anywhere in your page hirarchy. You could try by adding an `addOrReplace(jsonLabel)` after you created it in your onclick funtion. Still, that whole thing would be much better solved by creating a Label with a dynamic model that automatically loads the data each time it is refreshed via ajax.

Comment: I'm new to the wicket. can you tell me how to create Label with a dynamic model. And i tried addOrReplace(jsonLabel) but is not working

Comment: Hi. What's the expected behavior of you application? Do you get any kind of error running your code?

Comment: The expected behavior is to show JSON data when "View Template" is clicked. I'm getting the following error. `org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Unable to find component with id 'jsonLabel' in [JsonDataPanel [Component id = dataPanel]]
 Expected: 'dataPanel:jsonLabel'.
 Found with similar names: ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Label as a sibling of the AjaxLink:

```
final Label jsonLabel = new Label("jsonLabel", Model.of(""));
jsonLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
AjaxLink<Void> jsonData = new AjaxLink<Void>("jsonData") {

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            File jsonFile;
            try {
                jsonFile = new File(fileLocation);

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        
                JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, JsonNode.class);
                // just update the Label's model and re-paint it
                jsonLabel.setModelObject(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonNode));
                target.add(jsonLabel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    add(jsonData, jsonLabel);
```

Your HTML is OK.

Comment: Before clicking "View Template" link, it is showing empty line because of `<pre>` tag. Is there any way to hide that empty line.